# Chrome headless won't render JavaScript content to a text file from the Windows command line

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome-headless

I want chrome headless to return JavaScript-base content into the text file, `out.txt`. The Windows command-line below works fine for most URLs, but for the URL given below, `out.txt` is created successfully but empty. Why is this particular URL a problem, and how do I fix that?

```
windows> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom --enable-logging https://digital.fidelity.com/prgw/digital/research/quote/dashboard/summary?symbol=IBM > out.txt
```

- I tried removing the `--headless` flag, but that didn't help.
- I tried
  adding `& timeout 3` to the end of the command line, but that didn't
  help.

Could it be that the Chrome process exits before all the JavaScript is rendered? If so, how can I fix that easily on the command line?

I should add that the *entire* main body of this webpage is one compressed JavaScript script. If it must be parsed, it would have to be parsed while the JavaScript is rendered. Can that even be done on the command line, or is that impossible?  I would prefer the parse it as a separate operation *after* Chrome is done rendering it--if that's possible.

Comment: I'd use Selenium for this, something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896318/print-dom-after-selenium-driver-get with explicit sleep in between navigating and retrieving the render.

Comment: I'm not doing any navigating at all. I simply want to render the entire page "as loaded" without any navigation. And if you look at the page source, there's nothing to navigate on. There's just one compressed JavaScript script that generates all the body content.

Comment: Yes, and that would be doable with Selenium right away instead of trying to figure out what parameter to use with Chrome directly.